# Angular Callback not returning data to Angular promise

Tags: angularjs, callback, angular-promise

The createQuestionDataAsync is not returning data.  The flQuestion.create function makes a call to an express service that writes to a mongodb collection.  The question is written and the value comes back and stored in "data".  I could not set this up like a typical callback (err,data) as the response back only return one value.  Maybe I need to make this a promise?  Or can I keep a callback with some modification?

angular.module('app').factory('flQuestionCrud',function($http, $q, $state, flQuestion ){
    return {
        createNewQuestion: function(newQuestionData) {
            console.log("Before - flQuestion.create");

```
        // Question Call Back Function
        function questionCallBack(err, data){
            if (err){
                console.log("flQuestionCrud - Error " + err);
                console.log("flQuestionCrud - Error Statement " + err);
                return null;
                //$state.go('questionCreate');
            }else {
                console.log("flQuestionCrud - Success " + data);
                console.log("flQuestionCrud - Success Statement " + data.statement);
                console.log("flQuestionCrud - Success Question id " + data._id);
                return data;
                //$state.go('questionUpdate');
            }
        }

        // Try/catch
        function createQuestionDataAsync(questionData, cb) {
            console.log("flQuestionCrud - Before Call to create ")
            flQuestion.create(questionData, function(data) {
                console.log("flQuestionCrud - After Call to create ")
                if (!data){
                    return cb("Error Creating Data");
                    //return null;
                }
                try {
                    console.log("flQuestionCrud - Try Section - Success " + data);
                    console.log("flQuestionCrud - Try Section - Success Statement " + data.statement);
                    console.log("flQuestionCrud - Try Section - Success Question id " + data._id);
                }
                catch (err) {
                    return cb("Error Creating Data");
                    //return null;
                }
                return cb(null,data);
                //return data;
            });
        }

        createQuestionDataAsync(newQuestionData,questionCallBack);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback is node callback style. Angular does not use this type of callback. The returned value contains `data` field where the actual response is stored.

This assumes you use `$http`